# In scala, compile error goes away when adding irrelevant line after toMap

Tags: scala

This is cross-posted from the coursera functional programming course because there's a lot less activity on that forum.

I wrote the following code (parts are redacted because it's homework):

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]
def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = {
  val mx: Map[Char, Int] = x toMap
  y.foldLeft (redacted) (redacted => simple expression using updated and -)) toList
}
```

This produces the following compile error:

```
type mismatch; found : Map[Char,Int] required: <:<[(Char, Int), (?, ?)]
```

However if I add a copy of the third line, without the toList, in between via a val statement, the error goes away:

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]
def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = {
  val mx: Map[Char, Int] = x toMap
  val foo: Map[Char, Int] = y.foldLeft (redacted) (redacted => simple expression using updated and -))
  y.foldLeft (redacted) (redacted => simple expression using updated and -)) toList
}
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with giving some kind of extra hint to the type checker, but does anyone know specifically why this happens?

Comment: Why a downvote with no comment?

Comment: It thinks the `y.foldLeft` is an argument to `toMap` (replacing the normal implicit that specifies the type).  Add a semicolon after `toMap` and you should be fine.

Comment: or just put a dot : x.toMap

Comment: I don't understand neither the close vote, nor the downvote. I think the question is interesting and fits SO. It illustrates well semi-colon inference problems with postfix operators.

Comment: I agree it's too localized but I also believe it can be improved. It's too localized because @jonderry didn't try to extract a minimum working sample from this code.

Comment: @pedrofurla - I should have explained my close vote (I didn't downvote): too localized because the example is large enough that it looks like it could be a very specific problem (i.e. it will come up in this homework and nowhere else) _and_ the subject line is only marginally likely to lead other people with the same problem to this answer.  This might be a duplicate also; I didn't look for it since even if not this didn't seem like the best way to answer it.  Maybe I should have instead rewritten the question.

Comment: @RexKerr, i don't disagree with you at all. Maybe now that I gave an answer the author can rewrite the question himself. And yes, it's quite likely it's a duplicate but I have no idea which keywords use to find the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, pedrofurla, I searched pretty hard for an answer and experimented a bunch in the editor. Probably the same issue is manifested in another question elsewhere, but it's not a duplicate if I can't search the site and figure out how to resolve my problem because I don't know what keywords will cause the problem to show up. IMHO it's not a bad thing to have multiple questions that have a common problem. Someone else in the future may have the same problem as me and be searching with keywords from my problem and find their answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below follows a few examples and some explanations on why it happens.

First, a working and a non-working cases:

```
scala> { List('a -> 1, 'b -> 2).toMap
     | println("aaa") }
aaa

scala> { List('a -> 1, 'b -> 2) toMap
     | println("aaa") }
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: <:<[(Symbol, Int),(?, ?)]
              println("aaa") }
                     ^
```

This happens because the syntax "obj method arg" is considered to be "obj.method(arg)" and so is "obj method \n arg", this way the argument can be written in the next line. Notice below:

```
scala> { val x = List('a -> 1, 'b -> 2) map 
     | identity
     | 
     | println(x) }
List(('a,1), ('b,2))
```

It's the same as `List('a -> 1, 'b -> 2).map(identity)`.

Now for the weird error message `found   : Unit, required: <:<[(Symbol, Int),(?, ?)]`. It happens that `toMap` actually takes one argument, here is it's signature:

`def toMap[T, U](implicit ev: <:<[A,(T, U)]): Map[T,U]`,

but it's an implicit argument, so doesn't need to be provided explicitly in this case. But when you use the `obj method \n arg` syntax it fills the method argument. In the above non-working example the argument is `println` which has type `Unit`, hence it is not accepted by the compiler.

One workaround is to have two `\n` to separate the lines:

```
scala> { List('a -> 1, 'b -> 2) toMap
     | 
     | println("aaa") }
aaa
```

You can also use a `;` to separate the lines.

Answer (score 2):

@RexKerr & @DidierDupont are right, you're having issues because you called `toMap` like a binary operator, so the compiler freaked out.

My two cents: you should probably read the [Suffix Notation section of the Scala Style Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#suffix_notation).